# Check if all items within sub-array are identical Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sub-array

Trying to check if all items within sub-arrays are the same. For example, I have a 5x5 board and I want to know if one of the arrays contains all `x's`:

```
board =     [[47, 44, 71, 8, 88],
        ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'],
      # [83, 85, 97, 'x', 57],
        [83, 85, 97, 89, 57],
        [25, 31, 96, 68, 51],
        [75, 70, 54, 80, 83]]
```

I currently have:

```
def check_x
  board.each do |x|
   return true if x.include?('x')
  end
   return false
end
```

But this will merely check if one of the integers is `x` and not all. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question indicates you are looking for an element of `board` (a row of the playing board) that contains all `x`'s, but your title and first sentence suggest you looking for an element of `board` whose elements are all the same, but not any particular value.  Please edit to clarify whether all elements of a row must be the same or must equal a specified  value.

Comment: If you are not inclined to edit your question to clarify, I would appreciate the courtesy of a reply to my comment.

Answer (score 6):

A bit more idiomatic:

`board.one? { |row| row.all? { |item| item == 'x' } }`

Comment: Interestingly enough I have tried both solutions. However, when attempting @kiddorails solution, the output still rings true if there is only one 'x', and I need it to ring true if only ALL are 'x'. I did use `board.one?` and that did work. Although I am unfamiliar with exactly how `.one?` works.

Comment: `Enumerable#one?` takes each entry in the container and passes it to the given block. If the block evaluates to `true` for exactly one record, the whole method returns `true`.

Comment: If you want strictly one row to have all "x", keep the `one?`. Otherwise use `any?`, which means at least one row is all "x"

Answer (score 2):

As simple as `board.map { |row| row.uniq.count == 1 }` will do
`#=> [false, true, false, false, false]`

[`uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) returns unique elements in an array. `map` here is iterating over your array and passing one row at a time to the block. It will return `true` for cases where all elements in an array are same (`['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'].uniq #=> ['x']` whose length is 1)

If you just want to check if **any** row in board has all duplicate elements, ruby has just a function. Guess what? [`any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F). Just change above one-liner with `any?` as:

`board.any? { |row| row.uniq.count == 1 } #=> true`

If you want to find out which row(s) has/have all the duplicates, and what duplicate it has:

```
board.each.with_index.select { |row, index| row.uniq.count == 1 }
#=> [[["x", "x", "x", "x", "x"], 1]], where 1 is index.
```

Pure Ruby awesomeness.

Comment: Added more information to play around with Ruby arrays.

Comment: This didn't seem to work when I ran it with board having only one 'x'. Still came back as true when I'm looking for it to only return true if all items within array are 'x'.

Comment: Can you give the `board` object in question in this case? Didn't fully get the scenario.

Comment: Beware that if the row is all filled with `1` or any other identical value, `uniq` will still return `true`, even though it's not `x`'s.

Comment: @ma_li: Travis stated " if all items within sub-arrays are the same", I don't think he is only expecting the `x` to be there to check the duplicates. `x` is just an example.

Comment: So take for example the commented out sub-array i just added. In that sub-array we have just one 'x'. This one 'x' returns true even though they aren't all true.

Comment: @TravisSiebenhaar It returns true only for 2nd row and not the commented row: `board.map { |row| row.uniq.count == 1 }
#=> [false, true, false, false, false, false]`, `board.each.with_index.select { |row, index| row.uniq.count == 1 }
#=> [[["x", "x", "x", "x", "x"], 1]]`

Comment: @kiddorails It appears your solution would be more ideal in a scenario where the user may be, like you said, expecting other items rather than just only the `x`.

Comment: Did I understand and answered your doubt correctly? The commented out row in your example will not return true by code above since, all elements in that subarray are NOT same.

Comment: This will not work fully, because we don't know for sure if we won't have an array of [12, 12, 12, 12, 12].  So you need to double check that the values are `'x'` @kiddorails

Answer (score 0):

if all elements are same in an array, that means maximum and minimum is equal. 
for your board you can find index of desired sub-array with this one line

```
board.each {|b| puts board.index(b) if b.max == b.min}
```

or just replace `x.include?("x")` with `x.min == x.max` in your function for true/false result

Comment: if a row of board is `[1,'x']`, `[1,'x'].max #=> ArgumentError: comparison of String with 1 failed`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland look at the sentence before the last one in OP.  
"but this will merely check if one of the integers is x and not all".

Comment: The penultimate sentence? :-) Yes, Travis is explaining why his code doesn't work. Suppose `board = [['x',1],['x','x']]`. Then your code returns `ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with String failed`. Specifically, it is `['x',1].max` that failed..

Comment: that means i've totally misunderstood :) i just thought that the `x` is just placeholder. there can be any other integer number and it seemed more rational to me

Comment: I'm pretty sure `'x'` is meant to be a string, because of the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all elements of `board` (rows of the board) are the same size, which seems a reasonable assumption, you could do it thus:

```
x_row = ['x']*board.first.size
  #=> ["x", "x", "x", "x", "x"] 
board.any? { |row| row == x_row }
  #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's always a fixed length array, your method can just be:

```
def full_row
  board.each do |row| 
    return true if (row.uniq.count == 1) && (row[0] == 'x')
  end

  return false
end
```

This could be boiled down to fewer lines, but I hate line wrapping in vim :p